# Importing a similar column (eg. pH column) from 60 csv files thru use of loop and making a matrix .

Tags: r

I want to create a loop that reads a specific column (Lets say pH) in a directory of 60 csv files and write that column in csv file next to each other as the order of files in the directory.

```
directory <- "C:/"
file_name <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".csv")
files.to.read <- paste(directory,  file_name, sep="/")
for (i in 1:length(files.to.read)) {
  dta <- read.csv(files.to.read[i], header=TRUE)
  x<-dta$pH_
}
```

How can I code this to give me a csv file with 60 columns of x next to each other. Note that the number of rows are not necessary equal in all the files so when I cbind them, it gives me an error. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
directory <- "C:/"
file_name <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".csv")
files.to.read <- paste(directory,  file_name, sep="/")
x<-list()
```

I'd suggest storing your data from your CSVs in a list:

```
for (i in 1:length(files.to.read)) {
  dta <- read.csv(files.to.read[i], header=TRUE)
  x[[i]]<-dta$pH
}
```

Make a null variable to store the lengths of each pH dataset

```
ListLength<-NULL


for (i in 1:length(x)){
  ListLength<-c(ListLength, length(x[[i]]))
}
```

Then make another variable to determine how short each column will be from the longest pH dataset. Call this ManyNAs

```
ManyNAs<-max(ListLength)-ListLength
```

Make a null dataframe that has as many rows as your longest pH dataset.

```
OutputDF<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = max(ListLength), ncol = length(file_name)))
```

Then add in additional NAs to make dataframe happy.

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  OutputDF[,i]<-c(x[[i]],rep(NA, ManyNAs[i]))

}

write.csv(OutputDF, "OutputDF.csv")
```

If you really don't want NAs in your final CSV file you can do this:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){
   OutputDF[,i]<-c(x[[i]],rep("",ManyNAs[i]))
}
```

Comment: Thank you a million. I really appreciate it. It worked very good for me. Cheers.

Comment: Glad to do it. This kinda thing is a fun puzzle. I'd also recommend naming your columns based on the file they came from, just in case. Quick and dirty way is `colnames(OutputDF)<-c(file_name)`

Comment: Or for a even cleaner column name without .csv at the end you can do: `NewColumns<-sapply(file_name, function(x) substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-4))` and then: `colnames(OutputDF)<-c(NewColumns)`

Comment: I did that and it looks exactly what I wanted it. Oh man, I struggled with this a lot. I am new with R work. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: It can be a little tough to get up to speed, but keep at it. And don't ever be afraid to post on here. I'd also recommend this: https://www.coursera.org/learn/r-programming

Comment: Awesome. Thank for the encouragement brother. Peace